# Tera Term - waiting until user can input

Tags: teraterm

I'm using Tera Term to communicate with a circuit board in serial communication, and the commands I send give outputs according to the command.

With some commands, it takes a while before I can send another command (when I try to write nothing happens). I want to write a script that **waits until that happens**, and only when it does, send another command.

So just to be clear:

```
send command_1
wait until user can input
send command_2
...
```

I can't really use *waitln* because after it outputs the same thing for 4 times, and when I tried that, the script just sent the commands after the first time, which is something that is not supposed to happen (obviously a user cannot do that, therefore it's invalid).

Another option for me would be to initiallize some counter which would count the number of times these words appear ("Burn done" in my case) and when it reaches 4, send another command. is that possible?

I don't mind using Procomm plus, if needed, but I prefer Tera Term.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait until after a certain number of lines you can just put empty `waitln` and it will wait for any line.

```
waitln ''
waitln ''
waitln ''
waitln ''
```

Or you could try just using a `pause` if it consistently takes the same amount of time between allowing inputs

`pause Time`